# How do I test the "App Process Killed" route on Android?

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In the flow diagram for an Android app activity lifecycle (shown below) there is a route by which the 'App process' is killed and `onDestroy()` is not called. It seems this is most commonly done to free up memory resources for a different activity.

All that is fine, but how do I test this scenario? Either on device or in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: You can test this through instrumentation test  case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you force stop your app, all BroadcastReceivers and also app widgets, which extend BroadcastReceiver, will stop working. See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240705/5015207) by Commonsware

So force stopping the app is not ideal for testing app behavior under low memory conditions. What else can you do?

- One option: write your own task killer app and use ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(). As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory

- Another option: manipulate the device settings as explained by Xavi Gil in his answer to [Simulate low battery & low memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26253635/5015207)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it seems to have caused the issue I'm trying to track down. I used Xavi Gil's answer, but I think that first option might be the best answer.

Comment: @Wex - I used this [code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Tasks/Nukesalot) by CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Navigate to your app
2. Press home button so the app will not get the onDestroy call
3. Go to system settings and find the right place to "force close" your app
4. Navigate back to your app

Important note: DO NOT use back button when leaving your app when you are going to system settings, use home button instead so the app does not get killed.

Comment: `use home button instead so the app does not get killed` Just to clear this up: There is no guarantee that your app will not be killed when you press the home button. Have a low resource device and even the default launcher might be "heavy" enough to get all apps in the background get killed by Android.

Comment: Yeah I know but this was just one example in the perfect world.

Comment: `Yeah I know` should have prevented you from mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most clean solution to test those life cycle is to enable the "Don't Keep Activities" settings in the developer settings on your device.

This way you even get your activity killed as soon as you start a new activity. So if you press back than the old activity will be recreated.

Comment: Tell me how this solution goes to that route what he wanted. This simply destroyes the activity through onDestroy... Or am I wrong?

Comment: Both path are the same. OnDestroy is, as you can see in the docs and in this diagram, not guaranteed to be called. So either your app dies in onStop or your activity is killed and onDestroy might be called. Based on the "not guaranteed to be called" you shouldn't add any code in onDestroy in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that enabling "Don't Keep Activities" kills the whole app process. So holes in this one too. You are correct with that code adding stuff tho. It should be in onPause and checked with isFinishing method.

Comment: When you consider the activity life cycle, both path are the same. The difference between "app process killed" and the "activity destroyed" path is only the lifecycle of the application class and the call to onDestroy. So closed you can get.

Comment: Ah now I got it. I've been running little slow today... :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)