# How to detect incoming call phone number in Android when app is killed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I want to detect incoming/outgoing call phone numbers when my app is not running, it is killed. I have implemented the following code by it only detects call if the app is running or in the background but not working when the app is killed.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        String outgoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        showToast(context,"Call Outgoing to "+outgoingPhoneNumber);
    }else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        String callEndedNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        showToast(context,"Call Ended to "+callEndedNumber);
    }else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        showToast(context, "Incoming call from "+ incomingNumber);
    }
}

private void  showToast(Context context, String message){

    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

Manifests

```
  <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: "it's dead, Dave". Dead things do not show vital signs and Android requires app to be manually started by user to make all the receivers work. Unless user friendly relaunch the app you may remain dead

Comment: Does this answers your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63352467/6419026

Comment: How trueCaller is doing that without making it as default call app?

Comment: Please try to read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService

Comment: "it is killed" -- what **precisely** do you mean by this? And, on what device/emulator have you tested this behavior?

Comment: Killed means the app is closed(not even running in the background). And I am not using the emulator. I am testing on Redmi 9 power device. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but you can create your custom calling app and then make it default by asking for permission. A demo app can be found [on this repository](https://github.com/Abror96/CustomPhoneDialer). Look at this app code and you might get it.