# Make Broadcast Receiver Alive when app is killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-process, android-workmanager, telephonymanager

I have created Broadcast Receiver for detect incoming call. It works fine when app is in foreground but it stopped working after kill app.
So i used **Work Manager** for achieve but it also wont work. I am not sure if i implemented Work Manager properly.

**Please help me to make Broadcast Receiver alive when app is killed also suggest me right way if i made any mistake for get the result.**

> PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
            try {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    Log.e("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }
 }
```

> PhoneStateWorkManager.java

```
public class PhoneStateWorkManager extends Worker {
PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver phoneStateBroadcastReceiver;

public PhoneStateWorkManager(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    if (phoneStateBroadcastReceiver == null) {
        phoneStateBroadcastReceiver = new PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver();
    }
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(phoneStateBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    return Result.success();
  }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addAutoStartup();
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints
            .Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED)
            .build();
    WorkRequest phoneStateRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
            .Builder(PhoneStateWorkManager.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).enqueue(phoneStateRequest);
}

private void addAutoStartup() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
        } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exc", String.valueOf(e));
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: did you found any solution? my broadcast receiver not working when app removed from the background? any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get callbacks when the phone state changes: `PhoneStateListener` and a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`.

I would recommend not using `PhoneStateListener` at all, and go with the `BroadcastReceiver` approach only, which can be setup via `AndroidManifest` which allows it to be called even when the app is not currently active.

See this tutorial: https://medium.com/@saishaddai/how-to-know-when-a-device-is-ringing-in-android-57e516d0ab42

Please note, that when an app is killed via "FORCE CLOSE" by the user, **all the app's broadcast receiver are immediately put on pause**, and the system prevents them from receiving future broadcasts until the user manually reopens that app.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240705/819355)

So as long as the user doesn't FORCE CLOSE your app, you should be able to receive phone state changes.